# Sci Fi book where a probe/AI comes to Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space

Books starts off a an AI/Probe enters the solar system. Probe/AI scan Earth looking for something. Man finds the probe/AI tells about an invasion in the future. AI/Probe helps speed up mankind's technology to aide in the future. AI and man trick Earth military into thinking they were going to test a hyper drive instead the shift/or phase out of time or to another dimension while the invasion/Earth attack takes place. The guy found the probe/AI turns himself into an AI.

Comment: So, the "probe/AI" tells him about an invasion in the future and near the end, the probe/AI turns him into an AI?

Comment: Fuzzy - I think it is in the middle as the aliens attack and the military phases out, the guy who finds the probe/AI stays behind and and gets turned into an AI.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like a book series by Richard Fox called [*The Ember War Saga*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/161511-the-ember-war-saga)

> In the near future, an alien probe arrives on Earth with a pivotal
>   mission: to determine if humanity has what it takes to survive the
>   impending invasion by a merciless armada. The probe discovers Marc
>   Ibarra, a young inventor who holds the key to a daring gambit that
>   could save a fraction of Earth's population. Humanity's only chance
>   lies with Ibarra's ability to keep a terrible secret and engineer the
>   planet down the narrow path to survival. Earth will need a fleet. One
>   with a hidden purpose. One strong enough to fight a battle against
>   annihilation.

The series has about nine books (starting with the titular ***[The Ember War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25830594-the-ember-war)***) and has spawned a couple of other smaller series.

[image]